# source a file everytime I start unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I created a few .sh files and put them under one of the directories under $PATH. Unfortunately every time I start a new session I have to source them if I want to use them. I did a google search and couldn't really find what I am looking for to not having to source these files.

I guess I can place a source all command at ~/.bashrc but there should be a way to get this done in a simple way.

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com, there's no programming involved.

Comment: Since it involves shell scripts, it seems OK to me.

Comment: Simpler than `for f in dir/*; do source "$f"; done`?

Comment: Why not make the files into simple commands (drop the `.sh` suffix) and run them when you need them?  If they're containing functions and aliases, then source them from `.bashrc` or add their content to `.bashrc`.

Comment: By 'source' do you mean you want the scripts run? If so, PATH has nothing to do with that, it just makes shell's see that they are there (instead of giving a full path to execute)

Comment: Went with :
for file in ~/bin/*.sh;do source "$file";done;
thanks tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say all of your scripts are under the `~/.functions` directory. Put this in your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
for file in ~/.functions/*
do
    . $file
done
```

This will source in all files in the `~/.functions` directory whenever you start a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcing all commands in `.bashrc` is the simple way.

You may want a sophisticated way of sourcing your start scripts by creating a specific directory, say `~/.start_scripts`, where you put all your commands, and write a loop in your `.bashrc` that sources whatever executable is in this directory. That way, you no longer have to edit `.bashrc` each time a new command is put in the `.start_scripts` directory.